# How to deal with users instead of dealing with Ip-Adressing?

Tags: java, p2p

I plan to write a P2P chat application in Java 7, where we have a list of contacts (like in an application like Skype). And, then we can ask each connected contact to start a chat session (like in Skype). But Java Socket implementation asks us to give the Ip-Adress of the other endPoint. This leads me to 2 main issues :

- managing an dynamic IP-Adress : particularly before the other endPoint user connection
- managing the fact that the other user can simply use another computer each time

So, what workaround can you advice me ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on some external infrastructure for identification. 
For example, one can use OpenPGP-signed messages and keys will identify the sender. PGP keys are signed and trusted and there exist centralized repositories of PGP keys for verification. In this case the IP address doesn't matter, but the sender still needs to know where to send messages to, i.e. you still need a directory (some server with known address) which will maintain IP<->User mappings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer : but I still think that there is a solution which does not imply creating a server. Particularly when I think about frameworks like Juxtapose (Too complex and does not manage dynamic IP Adressing) and AntHill (too complex, not enough documented). And I think that's the real definition of a P2P Ad Hoc infrastructure.

Comment: I've also found AllJoyn framework, but the native library crashes on my 64 bits Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: @LaurentBERNABE As you have noticed, those libraries don't handle dynamic IPs, and that's for a reason - there's no way to match ips and usernames. BTW take a look at our MsgConnect ( http://www.eldos.com/msgconnect/ ) - it is documented, simple and cross-platform.

Comment: Thank you very much. What are the main conditions in order to use the free version ?

Comment: @LaurentBERNABE MsgConnect is free for any non-commercial use. In-house automation in commercial businesses and/or development of publicly distributed software require a paid license, but the cost is minimal nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

The users should identify themselves with some ID, for example with an e-mail address or a login name.

You must create some "fix points" in the systems, e.g. a given IP address or domain name, where the clients can register themselves (there you can store the user ID).

Every time an IP address changes, the client will update it on server, so other clients, who request the contact information will get the new IP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to manage dynamic ip without creating a server ? Just in an ad hoc network ?

Comment: If you are on the same subnet, you can use multicast to find another client. But regarding the Internet (e.g. DSL lines) it's not working. For example, Skype also has a number of servers.

Comment: @LaurentBERNABE And also, on the Internet you have to deal with firewalls, NAT, proxies, etc.

Comment: But, for discovering other clients and for dealing with firewall/proxies/nat : frameworks like JXTA/Anthill manage to do it : so it's not impossible ? (In fact those libraries were either too complex or they did not have all features I was waiting for).